# Excel VBA deletes first cell copied into a sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code that copies specific cells to another sheet, with each new record receiving a new line. It appears to copy everything correctly when it is processing, as I can see the correct cells being copied across to the new sheet, including A1. However, when it completes this the first cell in the new sheet (A1) is always empty. 
Not sure what's gone wrong here, would be great if anyone has any ideas/suggestions?

Thanks in advance

```
Dim Countrows As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim serialid As String
Dim NextRow As Range
Dim backgrounddate As Date

Countrows = 0
'find last row in spreadsheet,
For k = 2 To Lastrow
    If IsEmpty(CallCalculate.Cells(k, 8)) = False Then

        Set NextRow = Range("A" & Countrows + 1)
        CallCalculate.Cells(k, 2).Copy

        BackgroundCalc.Activate
        NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=False

        serialid = CallCalculate.Cells(k, 2)

        'add date
        Set NextRow = Range("B" & Countrows + 1)
        CallCalculate.Cells(k, 9).Copy

        BackgroundCalc.Activate
        NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Transpose:=False

        backgrounddate = CallCalculate.Cells(k, 9)
        Set NextRow = Nothing
        Countrows = Countrows + 1

    End If
Next k
```

Comment: Difficult to guess. It is not coming from this code. Maybe some other code is triggered (i.e. some `Worksheet_Change` event) that resets `A1`...

Comment: Anyway you should be surely better off if you avoid activate and select stuff and work directly with qualified ranges. Try it, chances are it might solve the issue.

Comment: If you move `BackgroundCalc.Activate` prior to the start of the loop, your problem should go away.  But I have posted an answer which includes a refactored version of the code, which should be more robust.

Answer (score 2):

**If `CallCalculate` is active when the macro starts**, your first copied cell is being written to that sheet (overwriting anything that may have been in its cell A1 previously) rather than to the `BackgroundCalc` sheet.  Therefore cell A1 on `BackgroundCalc` will still be unchanged from before the macro ran (and that was probably blank).

A refactored version of your code (which will fix the bug at the same time) would be:

```
Dim Countrows As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim serialid As String
Dim backgrounddate As Date

Countrows = 0
'find last row in spreadsheet,
For k = 2 To Lastrow
    If Not IsEmpty(CallCalculate.Cells(k, "H")) Then
        Countrows = Countrows + 1

        serialid = CallCalculate.Cells(k, "B").Value
        BackgroundCalc.Cells(Countrows, "A").Value = serialid

        'add date
        backgrounddate = CDate(CallCalculate.Cells(k, "I").Value)
        BackgroundCalc.Cells(Countrows, "B").NumberFormat = CallCalculate.Cells(k, "I").NumberFormat
        BackgroundCalc.Cells(Countrows, "B").Value = backgrounddate
    End If
Next k
```